# Android Problems

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

I have a problem that i am trying to solve using android to develop and app for a trivia quiz so i need to start a quiz based on the category chosen. The problem is as follows:

Question 1
I cant seem to figure out how to pass the item selected from a ListView i can pass what is selected using spinner but not a list selection.

```
 private String getCategory(){
    final String category[] =new String[1];
    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.soloList);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View View, int position, long id) {
            category[0] =(String) (list.getItemAtPosition(position));
        }
    });
    return category[0];
}
```

That is the part of the code is use and cant seem to get it to work and my question is how do i make it work? I call the method within main but nothing ever gets passed.

Thanks.

Comment: Please break this into two separate questions, as they're completely unrelated.  As an aside, the best way to load data into an SQLite db is to just include an SQLite db file in the apk (you can get a desktop version of sqlite to help you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About Q1 :
You have function that return String it's ok but what's wrong that not made code work is ItemClickListener

First let me tell you about Interfaces in Java :
As you've already learned, objects define their interaction with the outside world through the methods that they expose. Methods form the object's interface with the outside world; the buttons on the front of your television set, for example, are the interface between you and the electrical wiring on the other side of its plastic casing. You press the "power" button to turn the television on and off. - [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

The problem in this code is that you set kind of interface on each item click, but you function not wait for item click callback to return result !

the way you can handle is :

1: Create Interface for Callback when user select new item on listview

```
public interface category {
   public void getCategory(String itemTitle);
}
```

2: set callback to you Activity Fragment or ...

```
public class ProjectList extends Fragment implements category
```

3: Override callback function

```
@Override
public void getCategory(String itemTitle) {
    // do something with new item !
}
```

4: Call callback function when item selected

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View View, int position, long id) {
        ProjectList.this.getCategory("newitem-String")
    }
});
```